# Deserialize XML Attributes to Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, serialization, deserialization

Suppose I am trying to deserialize the following XML (in a C# program):

```
<Data>
    <DataItem Id="1" Attrib1="Val1_1" Attrib2="Val2_1" Attrib3="Val3_1" />
    <DataItem Id="2" Attrib1="Val1_2" Attrib4="Val4_2" />
    <DataItem Id="3" Attrib3="Val3_1" Attrib5="Val5_3" />
</Data>
```

So, each `DataItem` element will have an `Id` field and a random set of attributes I'd like to capture / store.

I'm imagining the final containing classes could look as follows:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("Data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("DataItem")]
    public DataItem[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class DataItem
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Vals { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Id { get { return (string)Vals[Id]; } }
}
```

(If I'm wrong on this structure, PLEASE let me know - this is still all very new to me!!)

But I'm not sure how to deserialize the attributes into the `[Key][Value]` pairs for my dictionary.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3123921/1693085) and also [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5996183/1693085) that seem to be pointing me in the right (albeit different) directions, but I'm lost in how to implement this correctly and know this should be fairly easy.

Any help / links / samples on how this could be done would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Thanks!!!

Comment: There's no way you're going to do this with attributes.  You'll need to implement `IXmlSerializable` and manually write the serialization code for `DataItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as I suspected (and was suggested in the comments), I left aside direct XML serialization and wrote my own parsing method to accomplish this.

For anyone else this may help, here's what I ended up writing - Hope it helps you too (If anyone has a better answer, though, PLEASE do post it! - I'd love to see how else this could be accomplished / done better):

```
public class Data
{
    public List<DataItem> Items { get; set; }

    private Data(XElement root)
    {
        Items = new List<DataItem>();

        foreach (XElement el in root.Elements())
        {
            Items.Add(new DataItem(el));
        }
    }

    public static Data Load(Stream stream)
    {
        return new Data(XDocument.Load(stream).Root);
    }
}

public class DataItem
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Vals;
    public string Id { get { return (string)Vals["Id"]; } }

    public DataItem(XElement el)
        {
            Vals = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // Load all the element attributes into the Attributes Dictionary
            foreach (XAttribute att in el.Attributes())
            {
                string name = att.Name.ToString();
                string val = att.Value;

                Vals.Add(name, val);
            }
        }
}
```

Then it would be used in code fairly simply via:

```
Data MyData = Data.Load(MyXMLStream);
```

Hope this helps others too!!

Answer (score 1):

A more generic solution would be:

```
public class DynamicAttributes : IXmlSerializable, IDictionary<string, object>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _attributes;

    public DynamicAttributes()
    {
        _attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.HasAttributes)
        {
            while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
            {
                var key = reader.LocalName;
                var value = reader.Value;

                _attributes.Add(key, value);
            }

            // back to the owner of attributes
            reader.MoveToElement();
        }

        reader.ReadStartElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in _attributes)
        {
            writer.WriteStartAttribute(attribute.Key);

            writer.WriteValue(attribute.Value);

            writer.WriteEndAttribute();
        }
    }

    // implementation of IDictionary<string, object> comes here
}
```

Than the classes for your case would be:

```
[XmlRoot("Data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("DataItem")]
    public DataItem[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class DataItem : DynamicAttributes
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Id
    { 
        get
        {                
            return this.TryGetValue("Id", out var value) ? value.ToString() : null;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: That is really nice!!

Answer (score -3):

Use This

```
<Data>
    <DataItem Id="1" Val="Val1_1" />
    <DataItem Id="1" Val="Val2_1" />
    <DataItem Id="1" Val="Val3_1" />
    <DataItem Id="2" Val="Val1_2" />
    <DataItem Id="2" Val="Val4_2" />
    <DataItem Id="3" Val="Val3_1" />
    <DataItem Id="3" Val="Val5_3" />
</Data>
```

Comment: Sorry, @jdweng, that doesn't even make sense to me.... The XML is given, I'm asking how to de-serialize it to a dictionary....