# Deserialize xml data to a dictionary Key/Values pair using C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, xamarin.forms

Here i'm trying to Deserialize xml in dictionary key/values pair.Please help me on this?.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Cars>
    <Car name="BMW">
      <Keys>aaa</Keys>
      <values>12121</values>
    </Car>
   <Car name="Honda">
      <Keys>aaa</Keys>
      <values>12121</values>
    </Car>
     <Car name="Ford">
      <Keys>aaa</Keys>
      <values>12121</values>
    </Car>
   <Car name="Volkswagen">
      <Keys>aaa</Keys>
      <values>12121</values>
    </Car>
     <Cars>
```

Comment: what are the issues that you are getting?

Comment: You gotta post error messages and your code

Comment: What are the issues? You should edit your question to make it a question? Please read [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an XML-document to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710193/converting-an-xml-document-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: You should check these: (Deserializing xml to object with dictionary)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113248/deserializing-xml-to-object-with-dictionary] and [How to serialize/deserialize to `Dictionary<int, string>` from custom XML not using XElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554186/how-to-serialize-deserialize-to-dictionaryint-string-from-custom-xml-not-us)

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Anyone can provide the solution according to my requirement or POC

Comment: No we wont do your work for you.

Comment: @P.Roe Please don't work for me just i need your suggestion

Comment: The comments above will put you on the correct path. Once you've coded an attempt or two feel free to post questions about any of the specific errors you're seeing.

Comment: @P.Roe can you please suggest me what will be best approach to parse the above xml to c# in dictionary key/value pair?

Comment: this didn't work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710193/converting-an-xml-document-to-a-dictionary